# MockMultipartFile not working in real environment, as it is available in test package of spring. Is there any workaround for this?

Tags: java, spring, multipart

I have a file on my local disk, I want to convert that file to multipart file as I need to upload this file to another server. I am converting file to multipart file using MockMultipartFile, but it is not working as this package is only available in the test environment

I am trying to use CommonsMultipartFile instead of MockMultipartFile, but CommonsMultipartFile constructor needs an object of file item. I am not able to utilize that constructor

**Using MockMultipartFile::**

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(unzippedFile);
            return new MockMultipartFile(FILE_STRING, unzippedFile.getName(), MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream))
```

**Using CommonsMultipartFile::**

```
DiskFileItem diskFileItem = new DiskFileItem(FILE_STRING, MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, false, unzippedFile.getName(), (int) unzippedFile.length(), unzippedFile.getParentFile());
            diskFileItem.getOutputStream();
MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(diskFileItem);
```

I expect CommonsMultipartFile constructor to take diskFileItem, but it is giving an error

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a `MultiPartFile` to do uploading. Just create a proper request using an `InputStream` and then send it. You are making things overly complex by trying to shoehorn this in a multipart file.

Comment: I have to upload this file to spring, how can I send an InputStream to API

Comment: IT doesn't matter where you upload it to. It is basic HTTP. Create a regular form with the proper type and send the inputstream as well. It doesn't matter if the server you are sending to is build with Spring, PHP or technology Foo.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum for ur suggestions. I found a solution for it with ur inputs